# cor.test in R and na values

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation

I wonder how cor.test is dealing with NA values.

I have

```
a =  c(1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.0, 0.9)
b = 2*a
d = b
d[3] = NA

cor(a, d) = NA
```

but

```
cor.test(a, d) = 
Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  a and d
t = 94906000, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1 1
sample estimates:
cor 
  1
```

I guess cor.test is excluding NA and calculating the correlation on the rest. But I am not fully sure. Also, I am not sure, if it consider the same in p-value too or not ? I could not figure out the default setting either ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can read in the `cor.test` documetation,

> na.action: a function which indicates what should happen when the data
>   contain NAs. Defaults to getOption("na.action").

Checking the default setting (in the command line) with

```
getOption("na.action")
```

gives me

```
[1] "na.omit"
```

ADDED

Syntax of `cor` is different from that of `cor.test`. Use

```
cor(a, d, use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

to get a meaningful value

Comment: gives me the same thing ! but, when I apply na.omit, in the normal "cor(a,d, na.action=T)" still complains.

Comment: Use `cor(a, d, use="pairwise.complete.obs")`

Comment: Thanks ! and sorry for asking this again, does it mean, cor.test automatically omit NA and calculate the p-value based on left over ?

Comment: Yes. This is the default behaviour.